# my mongos's log write "scoped connection to not being returned to the pool "error,how do fix it

Tags: mongodb

When i check my mongo sharding database,i find alot of same errors at mongos log.It seems the database has some  wrongs:

```
Tue May 20 18:01:48.229 [conn11851] scoped connection to ts84_mongodb:27020,ts85_mongodb:27020,ts86_mongodb:27020 not being returned to the pool
Tue May 20 18:01:48.233 [conn11851] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [ts84_mongodb:27020]
Tue May 20 18:01:48.234 [conn11851] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [ts85_mongodb:27020]
Tue May 20 18:01:48.234 [conn11851] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [ts86_mongodb:27020]
```

And then,i checked other databases,including mongod and config databases,yet they are fine.I did not found any errors or warning information in their logs.
Why?
My mongodb shard use mongodb 2.4.9 version.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. after sync the cluster's time setting (using ntpdate), problem gone.

Comment: My servers have sync the cluster's time setting with ntpdate.But problem is not gone.